# Jakarta testnet RPC does not work

Tags: node, rpc, docker

I'm trying to run Jakarta testnet node locally. Node starts and syncs, but RPC does not work. `docker-compose.yaml` I'm using:

```
version: "2"
services:

  node:
    image: tezos/tezos:v13.0
    hostname: node
    command: tezos-node --network=jakartanet
    ports:
      - 9732:9732
    expose:
      - '8732'
    volumes:
      - node_data:/var/run/tezos/node
      - client_data:/var/run/tezos/client
    restart: on-failure

volumes:
  node_data:
  client_data:
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

This should fix the issue if you are calling the RPC from the host.

```
ports:
  - 9732:9732
  - 8732:8732
volumes:
   ...
```

Comment: didn't help, any other ideas?

Comment: Did you remove 'expose'? Can you show the logs? `docker-compose logs node`

Comment: Updating the node configuration...
May  9 16:10:33.192 - node.main: FULL access to RPC enabled; this is very risky. (addresses = :8732)
May  9 16:10:33.331 - node.config.validation: the node configuration has been successfully validated.
May  9 16:10:34.058 - node.config.validation: the node configuration has been successfully validated.
May  9 16:10:34.059 - node.main: read identity file (peer_id = idtjmcuW3dbKbpBVSGEGdTiuR96HCi)
May  9 16:10:34.060 - node.main: starting the Tezos node v13.0 (cb9f439e)
May  9 16:10:34.060 - node.main:   (chain = TEZOS_JAKARTANET_2022-04-27T15:00:00Z)

Comment: I can't paste here full output

Comment: Everything seems fine. The RPC call simply times out? Did your setup work fine with Ithacanet?